# How to get different elements from a List<List<string>>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a List containing several List of strings.

I'm looking for a LINQ query that can return a List containing all the different strings present in all the sub lists.

Is it possible to it with just one query?

Thanks.

```
List<string> a = {"a", "b", "c"}
List<string> b = {"c", "d", "e"}
List<List<string>> c = {a, b}
```

Expected result after doing a query over 'c':

```
List<string> result = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` first to flatten the `List<List<string>>` first and use `Distinct` then:

```
var input = new List<List<string>> {a,b};
var result = input.SelectMany(x=>x).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I always forget about SelectMany ... so useful and so ... forgettable? :)

Comment: @SoMoS not really, whenever you have a collection of collection ... you should think of the use of `SelectMany` :)